# Error "Cannot use instance member 'haberUrl' within property initializer"

Tags: swift, url

When I want to change a string to URL, I'm getting this error:

> "Cannot use instance member 'haberUrl' within property initializer;
>   property initializers run before 'self' is available."

What should I do?

```
var haberUrl = String()
var newsUrl = URL(String: haberUrl) //error in here
```

Comment: Beside your error: `var haberUrl = [String]()`: So `haberUrl` is an array of String objects. `URL(String: haberUrl)` That won't work, because `haberUrl` is not a String object, it's an array of String objects.

Comment: i change it but not work

Comment: As I said, that's another issue when you would have fixed your current problem. Now, you need to show more code, where is it written? The error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44648388/cannot-use-instance-member-server-within-property-initializer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the warning says, you can't reference another property in the instance when setting up a property - the object itself isn't initialised yet. Fortunately, in this case, it looks like you're setting the properties to default values. Just use a literal for the value you want for `newsUrl` (eg, `URL(string: http://example.net)`).

As an aside, given that `haberUrl` is an array of `String`, this would never have worked (`URL` expects a single string).

Comment: when i click this viewController its have a value  it initialised

Answer (score 1):

I can see two mistakes here :

- `haberUrl` is an Array, convert it to `String` instead of `[String]()`
- The URL constructor from string is `URL(string: String)`, so it should be 
  `var newsUrl = URL(string: haberUrl)`